# Using sed insert a character in the beginning of the line except line with pattern matched and empty line

Tags: sed

I am kinda stuck.. i have a file with the following data:

```
Group: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.   
POM Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
POM Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. https://www.lorem.org/
Embedded Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. )

Group: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  
POM Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
POM Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  https://Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Embedded Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. )
```

I want to add semicolon in the beginning of each line except line which starts with Group

**So i get end result like this:**

```
Group: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  
;POM Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
;POM Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  https://Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
;Embedded Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. )

Group: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  
;POM Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
;POM Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
;Embedded Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. )
```

**I can add do this with if the pattern doesnt matches:**

```
sed '/^Group:/! s/^/;/' index1.txt
```

But i would like ignore the empty lines.

what am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just enhance your match pattern to include empty line:

```
sed '/^Group:\|^$/! s/^/;/' index1.txt
```

This way empty line will also be untouched.

Comment: Alternatively, `sed '/^Group/!{/./s/^/;/;}'`

Comment: should this work with gsed too on mac?

i tried your answer but got the same result i.e. empty line also have ;

Comment: Perhaps you have \r at end of line. Try sed -n '/^$/!p'

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
sed '/^Group:\|^$/! s/^/;/' file
```

Comment: This is identical to rush's answer.

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, now I realize it, my internet got lost for a moment and I didn't see his answer before posting.

Answer (score 0):

With Posix sed :

```
 $ sed -e '/^Group:/! s/^./;&/' index.txt
```